# Websockets for client/server communication in chrome packaged app

Tags: python, websocket

I have thoroughly looked at the Chrome packaged app website and sample apps but I couldn't find any example related to websockets implementation in an app. I was wondering if there is any example or sample app that uses Websocket for client/server communication in Chrome app? If not then is there any guide? Is it even possible to use WebSocket? I am using Apache HTTP as my server which is in Python.

Comment: Is there anything you've tried to start with?  Any code?

Comment: I'm actually interested in this too.  I see the option for TCP in the Chrome Packaged App documentation, but nothing about ws or wss.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're asking about implementing a WebSocket server, because the browser natively supports the client. (Though if you wanted, you could definitely implement the WebSocket client because you have access to the raw TCP interface.)

The Chrome Apps has published a [sample WebSocket chat server](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/websocket-server) that servers HTTP requests to load the chat client and uses WebSockets to send messages between clients.

If you look through the [implementation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/websocket-server/http.js), you see it uses the older `chrome.socket` API to listen to a TCP socket and respond with the correct WebSocket HTTP headers. It does all the bit manipulation to send and receive frames of data as required by the WebSocket spec.